# Связи между таблицами JDBC

Tags: sql, jdbc, many-to-many, one-to-many

У меня есть таблицы Book, Genre
Каждая книга может иметь множество жанров. Какую связь лучше сделать между таблицами: One-to-Many или Many-to-Many?

Answer (score 2):

У книги может быть много жанров. В каждом жанре может быть много книг.

Значит связь нужна многие-ко-многим, то есть `many-to-many`.